# Adjusting spare sectors on SATA drive?

Tags: hard-drive, failover, drive-failure

As far as I know, hard drives usually have a number of spare sectors to which data is remapped/reallocated from faulty sectors.

Is it possible to increase the number of these spare sectors (at the expense of usable data capacity) to make the drive more reliable? Is there a standard way to do this on Linux?

**EDIT:** I was just wondering whether there was a good way to reuse the drive for something else, even with reduced capacity. The failing 3TB drive has 1176 bad sectors (less than 600 KiB or 0,0000200704% of its user-visible capacity), so it seems like a waste to just decommission it.

Comment: A 3 TB SATA drive goes for the likes of $100 including shipping. Why bother? Just pluck in a new one and call it a day. Your time to just ask this question and read answers to it probably cost your employer more than that...

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I'm not talking about a cheap $100 SATA drive here, and even if I were, I'm unlucky enough to be located in a not so privileged enough economy to consider that cheap. :)

Comment: Well, even a 3 TB midline SATA drive can be had for a few hundred dollars these days. Amazon lists the ST3000NM0033 for $163 + S&H, or alternatively the 4 TB ST4000NM0033 for $160 + S&H. Hardly exorbitant, but then again, it depends on the value we place on our users' data. For whatever reason, *the disk you have is failing.* Do you want to take the chance that the data will be okay on it? I wouldn't, *even on my personal system.* Storage devices is a perfectly reasonable cost of doing business if what you do involves computers in any way, which in your case it obviously does.

Comment: Nevermind the price, it's still a terrible waste.

Answer (score 3):

No, the spare capacity is managed by the hard drive controller, and is not accessible to the operating system.

That doesn't really matter, though. There are a *lot* more aspects to hard drives that can cause failure than just bad sectors. If you want to increase availability, use RAID.